# Eliminating epsilon-productions in grammar

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-grammar

I am wondering how to eliminate epsilon-productions in grammar:

```
 S → S0 
 S → 1
 S → AB
 B → AC
 A → ε
 C → ε
```

I know that because of `C → ε` and `A → ε` we have to rewrite:
`B → AC` as:

```
 B → A | C | AC
```

and `S → AB` as

```
S → A | B | AB
```

But production `A → ε` and `C → ε` seems to eliminate states A,B and C, leaving only productions:

```
 S → S0 | 0
 S → 1
```

Am I correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me rewrite your grammar a bit into the following grammar.

$\begin{align}
S &\rightarrow S0 \; | \; 1 \; | \; AB \\
B &\rightarrow AC \\
A &\rightarrow \varepsilon \\
C &\rightarrow \varepsilon
\end{align}$

Let's take the reduction step by step. First we eliminate $C \rightarrow \varepsilon$.

$\begin{align}
S &\rightarrow S0 \; | \; 1 \; | \; AB \\
B &\rightarrow A \\
A &\rightarrow \varepsilon
\end{align}$

Now we eliminate $A \rightarrow \varepsilon$.

$\begin{align}
S &\rightarrow S0 \; | \; 1 \; | \; B \\
B &\rightarrow \varepsilon
\end{align}$

Next we eliminate $B \rightarrow \varepsilon$.

$\begin{align}
S &\rightarrow S0 \; | \; 1 \; | \; \varepsilon \\
\end{align}$

which is our resulting grammar. Notice that this also makes sense intuitively since we can easily see from the grammar that if we take the rule $S \Rightarrow AB$ as our first derivation step, there is no possibility other than ending up with the empty string $\varepsilon$.